flutter: Launching... takes forever to complete
I'm developing a flutter project on my Mac Mini M1.
In my flutter project, select my actual iphone (iOS 17.4.1) as current device, Run Without Debugging, Flutter Launching... is just there forever, my app could not load.
Below is my flutter doctor output:
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.4, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

Restart my Mac, delete app on my iOS device and rerun. It still does not help.
Below is XCode console output when launching my project:
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
10.22.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
10.22.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.10.22.0 started
10.22.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)
10.22.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS044002] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at ...
10.22.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
10.22.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
10.22.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [...]) to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://0.0.0.0:60075/RUIB-EERxgs=/

How should I improve speed of launching flutter project on my iphone?

I just found out why Flutter lauching hangs there: because I chose to run the app wirelessly. It's strange that it had worked with wireless mode before.
Anyway, now I debug via lightning cable. Everything seems to work normally.
